# Mark your answer as Accepted

Tags: support, comments, accepted-answer

Sometimes I see questions where no answer is marked as Accepted
But there's an answer of the OP like that: "I found the solution myself..."

Should I comment him to mark his answer as Accepted?
Or should I ignore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your best judgement. If the answer looks good to you, you can comment to remind him to mark his own answer as accepted.